# How does CloudKit Dashboard count Record Types?

Tags: ios, count, cloudkit

I am seeing higher-than-expected numbers in the CloudKit dashboard "Record Types" pane for the two record types I have created ("Groups" and "Members"). Although I currently only hold 7 Groups and 40 Members, I see counts of 48 Group records, and 2.3k Member records.

I think these numbers are cumulative from previous tests, which have been larger scale. Is it normal for all deleted records to be retained in some form, or am I not cleaning them up properly?

I create and delete records in batches, using

```
CKModifyRecordsOperation *op=[[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:recordsToSaveList recordIDsToDelete:recordsToDeleteList];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes is the answer me thinks, at least I'v seen a similar behaviour. CloudKit is obviously a large forest of servers and it takes a while for it to get its t's crossed and i's dotted.

You must have a similar experience with record deletion, especially ones that are linked thru references. Try reseting it completely and you should see it clear down, although obviously be careful cause a reset clears EVERYTHING including your record definitions.